# Running a line just once in recursive functions

Tags: matlab, recursion

If my function is recursive, how do I run a line on just the first recursion? I don't want the line to be run with every recursion.

Comment: Usually, if you want to do something _conditionally_, you use _conditional statement_, which use `if` keyword. What exactly is unclear to you?

Comment: I think that's a perfect valid and interesting question. Why the negative vote? You have two good answers on how to approach the problem.

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki I think (it wasn't me) the downvote was not about the question as such, but more that he didn't really give an example, did not tell us what he tried so far, that sort of stuff.

Comment: Agree, but he's asking a conceptual question that goes beyond an specific language or implementation. So even if no example is provided I'd still consider the question as a good one.

Comment: Agree, that is why I voted it back up ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would probably write a wrapper function for this, so you would get something like this:

```
function do_stuff() {
    do_stuff_only_once()
    do_recursive_stuff()
}

function do_recursive_stuff() {
    do_base_stuff()
    do_recursive_stuff()
}
```

This way you are not doing an `if` statement in every single function call, which should improve scalability a bit.

Answer (score 0):

```
function recursiveFunction(tempValue) {

   if(tempValue==1) {
     //exceute code one line code
   }
   // other function code here
   recursiveFunction(tempValue++)
}


/*Call function */

recursiveFunction(1)
```

Comment: You don't need to increment it every single time you call the function. Just set it to something else and be done with it, save some calculations.

Comment: yes i know it , I just put it to differentiate first call

Answer (score 0):

You could use [dbstack](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dbstack.html). If I have a function like below

```
function tmp(iter)
    x = dbstack;
    disp(length(x));
    if iter < 10
        tmp(iter+1)
    end
```

When I call it it displays how many functions deep my code is. The problem is that if I want to use it in many places the length of dbstack will not be enough. In that case, I'd have to use the name field of the dbstack struct. If I want to something just once, it'd look like this

```
function tmp(iter)
    %get the function list
    x = dbstack; 
    %convert the function names into a cell array
    func_names = {x.name}; 
    %create a logical array of which functions match the name
    name_matches = strcmp(func_names,'tmp');
    %if there's only one match, we do it
    if sum(name_matches) <= 1 
        disp('ONCE!');
    end
    disp('EVERY TIME!'); 
    if iter < 10 %make a few recursive calls to demonstrate the function
        tmp(iter + 1);
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use a **persistent variable:**

A persistent variable retains its value for multiple calls to the function. This is ideal if you have a value to initialize.

```
function tmp()
    persistent already_done

    if isempty(already_done)
        disp('once');
        already_done = true;
    end
```